# Controlling zoom on gmaps4rails with openlayers provider

Tags: gmaps4rails

I am trying to control the zoom level of a map that is using openlayers as the map provider.

```
gmaps({
    "map_options" => { "provider" => "openlayers",
                       "auto_zoom" => false, "zoom" => 12 },
    "markers"     => { "data" => @json }
})
```

The map (from OpenStreetMap) gets displayed but the zoom level remains the same no matter what value I use for the `zoom` option. The same code above without the `"provider" => "openlayers"` option works as expected for google maps.

The wiki for gmaps4rails has a link to a spreadsheet which states that "Zoom" is supported (but not "auto-zoom") for OpenLayers API.

So, is zoom control supported? Or am I doing something wrong?